# auth0 state missing from the response when using WebAuth and nextjs-auth0

Tags: next.js, auth0

I am using [nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0). I created a Regular Web Application in Auth0, nextjs-auth0 adds a state parameter to the URL, upon successful login, auth0 redirects back to my Next.js application, is is where the error "state missing from the response" occurs, I cannot see the state in the url and in the console I see

```
Cookie “state” has been rejected because it is already expired. callback
Cookie “_state” has been rejected because it is already expired. callback
Cookie “max_age” has been rejected because it is already expired. callback
Cookie “_max_age” has been rejected because it is already expired. callback
Cookie “code_verifier” has been rejected because it is already expired. callback
Cookie “_code_verifier” has been rejected because it is already expired. callback
Cookie “nonce” has been rejected because it is already expired. callback
Cookie “_nonce” has been rejected because it is already expired.
```

I tried to create a new tenant with a boilerplate universal login page and that seems to work

```html
<script>
  // Decode utf8 characters properly
  var config = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob('@@config@@'))));
  config.extraParams = config.extraParams || {};
  var connection = config.connection;
  var prompt = config.prompt;
  var languageDictionary;
  var language;

  if (config.dict && config.dict.signin && config.dict.signin.title) {
    languageDictionary = { title: config.dict.signin.title };
  } else if (typeof config.dict === 'string') {
    language = config.dict;
  }
  var loginHint = config.extraParams.login_hint;

  var lock = new Auth0LockPasswordless(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
    auth: {
      redirectUrl: config.callbackURL,
      responseType: (config.internalOptions || {}).response_type ||
        (config.callbackOnLocationHash ? 'token' : 'code'),
      params: config.internalOptions
    },
    configurationBaseUrl: config.clientConfigurationBaseUrl,
    overrides: {
      __tenant: config.auth0Tenant,
      __token_issuer: config.authorizationServer.issuer
    },
    assetsUrl:  config.assetsUrl,
    allowedConnections: connection ? [connection] : null,
    rememberLastLogin: !prompt,
    language: language,
    languageBaseUrl: config.languageBaseUrl,
    languageDictionary: languageDictionary,
    theme: {
      //logo:            'YOUR LOGO HERE',
      //primaryColor:    'green'
    },
    closable: false
  });

  lock.show();
</script>
```

However for my existing universal login page it does not, (trimmed):

```js
var params = Object.assign({
  domain: config.auth0Domain,
  clientID: config.clientID,
  redirectUri: config.callbackURL,
  scope: 'openid',
  audience: audience,
  responseType: 'token',
}, config.internalOptions)
var webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth(params)

webAuth.passwordlessVerify(values, function(err, res) {
  hide(loader)
  if (err) return postError(err)
})
```

How can I make sure the state parameter is sent so nextjs-auth0 can pick it up?